# What is the monero-wallet-rpc/deamon-rpc?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

What are they used for?

What does it mean http request? Does that mean it gets information directly from a website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`monero-wallet-rpc` is one of the command-line applications that ships with Monero. It enables developers to make HTTP based requests to interact with a Monero wallet. An example could be to implement the receiving of payments in XMR on an ecommerce site.

The other RPC is the daemon RPC which is part of the main `monerod` application. This enables developers to make HTTP based requests to interact with a node. An example could be someone wishing to develop a Monero blockchain explorer website.

In simplistic terms, you can think of both these apps as web servers, but instead of serving a web page (like a normal web server does), they return data that can be parsed and used in another application. The data they return is JSON data. Both of these RPC interfaces are only of any use to developers and are not relevant to normal users of Monero.

If you are interested in learning more, here are some documentation links:

- Monero Daemon RPC - https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/daemon-rpc.html
- Monero Wallet RPC - https://ww.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html
- JSON - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
- RPC - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call
- HTTP - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I will have to take some time and read more about it.